# Error when trying to run a STAN script for Bayesian analysis

Tags: r, stan

When I try to run the script `Stan-Ymet-Xnom1grp-Mrobust-Example.r` by [John Kruschke](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/), I get the following error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warnmeldung:
Ausführung von Kommando 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="file28347d8d29ec.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file28347d8d29ec.o"' ergab Status 127 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file28347d8d29ec.cpp 2> file28347d8d29ec.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

Search on Internet did not return anything helpful for me. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have all the requirements already installed?

Comment: I think so, yes. The script even checks that in the beginning with "require(rstan)"

Comment: Looks you need `Rtools`. Do you have?

Comment: yes, I have. Do I need to connect them with R somehow?

Comment: A reboot of R solved it -.- thanks for your help and patience!